# Issues with dialog in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a pop up window with needed fields but suddenly I ran into a big amount of issues.
I admin that I'm a total newbie speaking about jquery, mvc or css, so I can't detect where the problem is.

The biggest issue is that submin buttons mentioned in div are doing nothing. They simply didn't work.

My div is:

```
<div id="filterPanel" title="Filter Options">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Vehicle", "Home", new { id = "Id" }))
    {       
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Search Criteria:</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="k-in" style="width: 100px; padding: 0; font-size: 0.9em;" type="text" id="model" name="model" value="@Model.Filter.Model"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>
                        @{
            var statusItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value="None",
                    Text="None",
                    Selected= Model.Filter.Status == "None" ? true : false
                },
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value="New",
                    Text="New",
                    Selected= Model.Filter.Status == "New" ? true : false
                }
            };
        }
        @Html.DropDownList("Status", statusItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "k-dropdown", @style= "width: 120px;font-size: 0.9em; padding: 0;"})

                    </td>
                </tr>                      
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="k-button" style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter" /></td>
                    <td><input class="k-button" style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter" value="Remove Filter" onclick="ClearFilter()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    }
        </div>
```

The second strange issue is the pop up call itself. Then window appeared, everything seems fine, for a few moments. Then I watch to the screen bottom and I see that after all css style, was added and empty, white space. Actually, when I tried to debug it, I saw that

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay ui front"></div>
```

was placed after footer. As I understand pop up window understand it as an... start point I guess...

And last one... how should I call additional scripts from pop up window? I mean, I have datepicker, but when I tried to add it in pop up window, it's worked but datepicker window appeared in a position where could be div itself if it wasn't a pop up. In onter words, outside the dialog.

My dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filterPanel').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true

    });

});

function OpenPanel() {
    $('#filterPanel').dialog("open");
}
```

Help me please to understand, what I am missing?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it might be because you're missing `FormMethod.Post` as the 3rd parameter of BeginForm.

have a look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no. I have already added FormMethod.Post, and... nothing changed at all.

Comment: I don't think the second button should be of type `submit`

Comment: Why? Anyway, I commented one of them and it also doesn't changed a thing.