# Submit button issue in dialog (MVC4)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

No matter what, submit buttons are not working in my dialog. At all.

Not only with my own code, but also in a simple sample:

```
<div id="dialog">
    Your non-modal dialog
    <input style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter2" value="Filter" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#open').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
                    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

No reaction at all. Nothing is called in the HomeController. Even fiddler does't react on this submit button at all.

I can't get it, what am I missing? First of all I thinked that this is jQuert weird reaction on kendo theme, but this doesn't seems right.

Edit:
Actually I have already asked similar thing, but there are div which I use:
[All bunch of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037332/issues-with-dialog-in-mvc-4)

Comment: why `$('#open').click(..` is outside `document.ready`? It should be inside

Comment: Where is your form? Chances are jQuery UI is creating the dialog outside of it

Comment: Firstly, where is `HomeController` and why would that have anything to do with this?  I guess you'll want to use `$` consistently instead of mixing `$` and `jQuery`

Comment: _Even fiddler does't react on this submit button at all._....and why this should react you don't have `#open` id to your submit at all.

Comment: i think the #open button comes after you have written your script..make this script the last thing in ur html

Comment: doesn't changed a thing.

Comment: RGraham: what do you mean by form? Do you want me to add entire page? As about creating the dialog outside - well, each time dialor appears, its crush ,y css style (adds some strange white space out of nowhere in the page bottom, equal of dialog height).

Comment: Rob Schmuecker: ...its MVC and I want to call action? I used to call it without dialog, but now I need to hide some buttons inside pop up window. Trying to do it, I'm started to get a bunch of issues. And this is NOT my code, I told already that I can't run even this example.

Comment: Jai: Sorry, didn't understand you... :(

Answer (score 2):

The Submit button sometimes creates problem inside dialog, you can try to trigger submit button with Jquery as:

`$('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');`

**and just put a form tag in dialog also as shown below.**

OR

```
<div id="dialog">
<form action="// where you want to post form //" method="post">
....
....
<input style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #ff6a00; width: 100px" type="submit" name="filter2" value="Filter" />
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#open').click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @downvoter what is wrong in my answer???

Comment: Don't know who downvoted but... this thing, where should it be placed? If it is placed inside $(document).ready(function () { - its began calling it without a stop.

Comment: just wrap a form inside dialog and with my code you will redirect to whatever action action you will give inside form tag..

Comment: Still didn't get it. I'm sorry, I am newbie speaking of jQuery and MVC itself, so probably my questions sounds really stupidly.

Comment: just do it as :  <form action="Controller/Action" method="post"></form>....just put this form inside div with id dialog.

Comment: And I still can't understand you. How it supposed to look? Could you please edit your answer and show it?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko-Just try it...

Comment: Tried. Nope. Does't change a thing. Well, thanks for attempt to help at least. This is a second day when I tried to find anything about this kind of issue but everyone simply ignores my questions :(

Comment: Okk..@OlegsJasjko your welcome...I m deleting my answer don't know why someone downvoted my answer...thankzz...

Comment: I guess it's because of $('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');. There are no usage of it at all.

Comment: if you want to submit your form and your input type submit is not working then it's the only option with jquery to trigger click...

Comment: Except that this are trigger submit without a stop, and as a result you can't do anything on a page.

Comment: Placing the Html.BeginForm inside the dialog div works perfectly.. @KartikeyaKhosla your ans saved my time. :)